# How to prevent Gradle from printing EXECUTING?

Tags: gradle

when I run my application using **gradle**, I see writing on `stdout` the following output:

```
./gradlew run
> Task :run
<=========----> 75% EXECUTING [19s]
```

This print goes on during the entire execution and it interferes with the output of my program, as it would happen in a classic race condition problem where multiple threads write on the same file simultaneously without synchronization. The result is that I see on screen something like:

```
Lorem ipsum[19s]
dolor sit amet
consectetur adipisci elit[20s]
<=========----> 75% EXECUTING [21s]
```

I wonder if there's a way to tell **gradle** to not print such *execution bar*, so to not interfere with the program output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the progress bar, use

`./gradlew run --console=plain`

Extract from [offical docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#rich_console):

> Set to plain to generate plain text only. This option disables all color and other rich output in the console output.